# Best way to map different JSON keys to same target columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, json, postgresql-9.6

I have CSV import data that comes from multiple vendors with 50+ different columns, and each vendor has slightly different naming.

Instead of trying to spend hours mapping all of the column names to a master table with tons of columns, instead I want to store the original CSV row as a JSON column, such as `csv_data`.

I also want to store a unique identifier that is shared by all of the vendors, like `email`.

So my columns in my `contacts table would be:

```
vendor_id
email
csv_data
```

Then I was hoping I could create a view or materialized view which I could start with a small subset of columns that I know I will need (and will spend time mapping). Then, if I ever need the new columns later I could modify the view with new mappings.

I was hoping I could do some kind of case switch, like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN vendor_id = 100 THEN
        csv_data->>'fullname' AS full_name,
        csv_data->>'age' AS age,
        ... etc ...
    WHEN vendor_id = 101 THEN
        csv_data->>'FULL NAME' AS full_name,
        csv_data->>'AGE' AS age,
        ... etc ...
    WHEN vendor_id = 102 THEN
        csv_data->>'full name' AS full_name,
        csv_data->>'cust_age' AS age,
        ... etc ...
  END
FROM contacts
```

Unfortunately this is a syntax error... is there any more sane way to do this? I couldn't come up with good ideas. I truly don't want to create some enormous mapping as so many of the column names are messy and probably will never be used. I want to store the data in case I need it, but for my 'results' query I want to create a nice clean mapping that I only add to when I need it.

I'm open to better ways of doing this overall as well. I was trying to avoid the nuclear route of the massive massive table. But I guess I would if I absolutely advised as the best way.

Comment: Will all vendors have the same set of target columns (but different JSON keys), or a varying number per vendor?

Comment: `UNION ALL` might be your friend here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, they will have the same target columns, and if it doesnt exist within that vendor (and their json) I just want it to be NULL (for example if vendor A and B offer phone, and C does not, I would have a phone column thats just NULL for vendor C)

Comment: Aside: Postgres 9.6 has reached EOL. Consider upgrading to a current version. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go that route, storing original JSON data (I suggest as `jsonb` rather than `json` - cleaner and faster to extract), then consider a **translation table with key names** for every relevant target column per vendor. Conveniently as another **single `jsonb` value**. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE key2col (
  vendor_id int PRIMARY KEY
, keys jsonb NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO key2col VALUES
  (100, '{"full_name":"fullname", "age":"age"}')
, (101, '{"full_name":"FULL NAME", "age":"AGE"}')
-- more ...
;
```

Then your **query** can simply be:

```
SELECT c.vendor_id, c.email
     , c.csv_data->>(k.keys->>'full_name') AS full_name
     , c.csv_data->>(k.keys->>'age') AS age
FROM   contacts c
LEFT   JOIN key2col k USING (vendor_id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7db98fcee3a2335ba1ff0df114ff1eb3)*

This is even fit for any varying set of key --> column translation per vendor. Every field that has no JSON key for the given vendor in `key2col.keys` will be `NULL`. Same if the vendor did not actually provide the declared key in `contacts.csv_data`.

The `LEFT JOIN` in the query retains rows from contacts without any registered columns. You may want a plain `JOIN` instead ...

Comment: Truly amazing ,thank you

Comment: That makes total sense

Comment: That is so amazingly clever, I love it.  How woudl I handle the case where vendor 101 doesnt provide age?

Comment: Well, for starters, you wouldn't use "age" to begin with, that being a wide-spread antipattern. Use "birthday" instead, which doesn't bitrot as quickly. That aside, if a vendor does not provide a key, the result is `NULL`. Seems ok?

Comment: Thanks, haha, yes age was just an example because "cust_biz_addr_iso1471" is less interesting

Comment: Ha, then I'll tolerate `age` for the example! :)