# Unique array values for this string_to_array

Tags: postgresql, join, query, schema, json

This is a follow-up to:

- [Best way to map different JSON keys to same target columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308684/best-way-to-map-different-json-keys-to-same-target-columns/308686#308686)

Based on these sample tables:

```
data_providers:
id | field_map
--------------
1  | {"segments": "SEGMENT IDS", "full_name": "FULL NAME"}

leads:
id | data_provider_id | email | data
------------------------------------
1  | 201              | hi@hi | {"SEGMENT IDS": "id1,id1,id1,id2,id3", "FULL NAME": "John Doe"}
2  | 201              | xx@xx | {"FULL NAME": "Billy Bob"}

desired output:

data_provider_id | email | full_name | segment
----------------------------------------------
201              | hi@hi | John Doe  | id1
201              | hi@hi | John Doe  | id2
201              | hi@hi | John Doe  | id3
201              | xx@xx | Billy Bob | NULL
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  leads.data_provider_id,
  leads.email,
  leads.data->>(p.field_map->>'full_name') AS full_name,
  segment
FROM leads
LEFT OUTER JOIN data_providers p ON p.id = leads.data_provider_id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(leads.data->>(p.field_map->>'segments'), ',')) AS segment ON true
```

This query is doing 2 particular things:

1. its joining on `data_providers` table to get the `field_map` column which contains a JSONB mapping if CSV column headers. So something like `{"segments": "SEGMENT ID", "full_name": "FULL NAME"}`
2. Within the `data` JSONB column of `leads`, there is a key (which I discover through the field map above) that contains a comma separated string of segment_ids (it comes in a CSV and they chose to put 2 values within 1 row). I want to split it so each segment_id gets its own row (and obviously all other columns remain the same on both rows).

I have 2 goals:

1. If there is an empty string or the key doesn't exist within the map, I want to return the row but just with NULL for the segment_id. I already got this working by changing `CROSS JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.
2. I'm trying to remove duplicates in segment ids, so if someone enters 'id1,id1' it should only produce 1 row. I do this because there is a unique index on that column for the materialized view.

I'm currently stuck on #2.

Comment: I think you will have a better chance of getting answer(s) if you provide a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14. Most people will just skip to the next question as soon as they realize they will have to create table- and insert- statement's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a subquery and throw in `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT l.data_provider_id
     , l.email
     , l.data->>(p.field_map->>'full_name') AS full_name
     , s.segment
FROM   leads l
LEFT   JOIN data_providers p ON p.id = l.data_provider_id
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT DISTINCT segment
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array(l.data->>(p.field_map->>'segment'), ',')) AS segment
   ) s ON true
```

Your `field_map` holds the key 'segment', not 'segments', btw.

You could even use this short syntax:

```
...
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(l.data->>(p.field_map->>'segment'), ','))
   ) s(segment) ON true
```

(But the last one might make unsuspecting SQL purists cringe.)

Original order of array elements is *not* preserved. If you need that, see:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

And use `GROUP BY` rather than `DISTINCT` and also aggregate the minimum ordinal position for each group of duplicates.

Comment: @Tallboy: I would have tested my solution if you had provided a fiddle ...

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will also provide fiddle if I can't get this working. You are the Postgres demigod